# Mapping 512KB main memory into 1KB cache homework question

Tags: caching, cpu-architecture, memory-address, cpu-cache, memory-mapping

I'm sorry if I made an error in posting this. Please let me know if I need to change anything.

I've received my computer architecture homework back and I missed this question. My professor's explanation didn't make sense to me, and I disagree with what he told me, so I am here asking what you guys think.

Here is the question:

A computer uses 16-bit memory addresses. Main memory is `512KB`, and the cache is `1KB` with `32B` per block. Given each of the following mapping functions, calculate the number of bits in each field of the memory address.

Here is how I worked through the direct mapping part of the problem:

Cache memory: `1KB (2^10)`, 16-bit memory addresses `(1 word = 2B) -> 1024B/2B = 512 words`, 16 words per block `(32B)` -> `512/16 = 32 cache memory blocks`.

Main memory: `512 KB (2^19)`, 16-bit memory addresses `(1 word = 2B) -> 524288B/2B = 256K words`, 16 words per block `(32B) -> 256K/16 = 16384 or 16K` main memory blocks.

I understand the word tag as such: `32B` per block allows for `16 16-bit` memory addresses per block. This (I believe) supports that: `1 word = 16 bits = 2 B -> 32B/2B = 16 words` in each block. This equates to `2^4 = 4 bits` for determining which word in the block, leaving `12 bits` for tag and block bits in the memory address.

Now, in order to map `16K` main memory blocks directly into `32` cache memory blocks, there will have to be `512` main memory blocks mapped to each cache memory block. So `512/16K` blocks per `1/32` blocks.

Here is where I am confused. Doesn't this require `9` tag bits, as `2^9 = 512` (main memory blocks possibly mapped into one cache memory block)?

For the block bits, which point to a particular block in the cache, this requires `5 bits`. `2^5 = 32`, blocks in cache memory.

This would require `18 bits` in the memory address.

Here is my professor's answer for this question:

`2^5 = 32 -> 5` Word bits

`(1KB)/(32B)` = 32 blocks -> 5 Block bits

`16 – 5 – 5 = 6` Tag bits

I did not realize I could simply subtract the required block and word bits to get the tag bits. But it still doesn't make sense to me. `2^6 = 64 blocks` per cache block. `64*32` gives `2048`. I can't wrap my head around this. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, the terminology that i learnt is slightly different but the principal should be the same for this explanation.

So cache will have multiple sets (sort of like a cell). And each set will have 1 cache line (containing 1 block of data) or multiple cache lines (each contain 1 block of data) (direct mapping or n-associativity mapping).

In mapping the main memory blocks to the cache, the main memory address (16 bit) is divided into 3 fields: **tag**, **index bits** and **offset bits**. A memory cell is 1 byte and a block is made up of a few cells

**Offset bits** are used to access the individual bytes of a memory block. Think of it as the offset on top of the block base address to get the byte you want (i assume your memory should be **byte-addressable** rather than word-addressable as it doesn't make sense to access 2B word as this would be inflexible) And here your prof/textbook call it as word bit. Hence if a block has 32 Bytes, there would be log2(block size) = **5 bits** needed to access the individuals cells in the mapped block.

**Index bits** (in direct mapped cache is called block bits too as the number of set is the same as the number of blocks in the cache) is used to **identify which set**/cache line/ cache block that the main memory block is mapped to the cache. There are 1KB/32B = 32 cache blocks in the cache. **As direct mapping is used, each set contain only 1 cache block and therefore there will be 32 set in this cache**. Thus to access the correct set in cache, 5 bits is needed and therefore **index bits = 5 bits**

**Tag** is a name to determine if the data block in cache is the correct one we are looking one from the main memory. As the address of main memory is 16 bit and we already know index and offset fields, it is easy to deduce that tag will need 16 - 5 - 5 6 bits. How we determine the tag is not really a concern as the block size and cache size (and hence no. of sets in cache is given here).

Comment: Please add some tags to this post, so the people interested in topics regarding Your problem can see it.